What is the proper beracha for a mandarin chicken salad?
According to Halacha, what is the proper beracha to recite on a mandarin chicken salad? Is it Shehakol, Ha'etz, Ha’adamah, or something else?

This is a complicated situation. Usually meat and chicken are the main ingredient in any mixture since they are more chashuv. However, in a salad it is more probable that you’re interested in the vegetables more than the chicken.
Brachos.org says it is shehakol.
Halachipedia mentions many others who say it depends on which ingredient is the majority (there are referring to chicken lo mein which is also a mixture of chicken and vegetables)

Even though my answer differs from yours, the reasoning is the same. The source in your answer assumes chicken is the main ingredient, I assume the salad is since the dish is called a salad. Note that, because of this, your first two paragraphs contradict each other.

In Hilchot Brachot, there is a rule called ikar v tafel (ikar is the main ingredient, tafel the secondary), by which one makes the blessing on the ikar and it exempts the tafel (based on the mishna in Brachot 44a). That rule applies to foods mixed together or where one is used to enhance the taste of the other.
The way to determine is the ikar is to determine which food is the most desired or (when difficult to say) which is in greater quantity. Foods made from the five grains are most often considered the ikar. At times this might be different from one person to the other (e.g., chocolate-covered raisins).
I find that a good trick is to follow the name of the dish, here you call it a salad, so ha'adama would work well, assuming in this salad the ikar is the salad. If you called it a mandarin chicken, the blessing would become sheakol.
Source: R Binyomin Forst's the laws of berachos, pp. 206ff (except for the trick which is mine).
PS. As every good rule, it has exceptions.
